# python3 cannot successfully compile the proto file

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, protocol-buffers

OS: windows 11

libprotoc 3.20.3

Python 3.10.9

I was trying to compile the proto file, there was no error message is prompted after I executed the command
"protoc --proto_path=C:\Work\test pm_event.proto --python_out=." but the DESCRIPTOR._options in the generated pb2.py file is always None, and all fields have only the starting/ending position info.

I can't provide the proto files, but I can confidently say that the proto files are correct, because my colleagues can successfully compile these proto files through Java

It seems something wrong with my env. I just made a very simple proto file:
example.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

message ExampleMessage {
  int32 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
}
```

And run the command "protoc --python_out=. example.proto" and got the output of example_pb2.py, the content as below

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: example.proto
"""Generated protocol buffer code."""
from google.protobuf.internal import builder as _builder
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pool as _descriptor_pool
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()




DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor_pool.Default().AddSerializedFile(b'\n\rexample.proto\"*\n\x0e\x45xampleMessage\x12\n\n\x02id\x18\x01 \x01(\x05\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x02 \x01(\tb\x06proto3')

_builder.BuildMessageAndEnumDescriptors(DESCRIPTOR, globals())
_builder.BuildTopDescriptorsAndMessages(DESCRIPTOR, 'example_pb2', globals())
if _descriptor._USE_C_DESCRIPTORS == False:

  DESCRIPTOR._options = None
  _EXAMPLEMESSAGE._serialized_start=17
  _EXAMPLEMESSAGE._serialized_end=59
# @@protoc_insertion_point(module_scope)
```

So what shall I do for the next?

Comment: If you can't provide the proto files, you should create some that you *can* provide (a minimal, but reproducible, test case). Asking for help while making it hard for people to help is *rarely* productive :-) Every good question (and, indeed, every good bug report) should include (1) steps to reproduce, (2) expected result, and (3) actual result.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will provide more detail information for this case.

Comment: Humor me here. Remove the `--proto_path=C:\Work\test` from your "bad" command and run it while you're in that directory. I'm wondering whether the backslashes could be causing an issue, especially the `\t` which could be treated as a tab ???

Comment: But it may be that what you're seeing is normal (as per answer from DazWilkin which I only read after making that previous comment so feel free to ignore it (the comment, not the answer)). I can't say for sure, we use `betterproto` rather than the Google stuff. Far more readable output than large BLOB structures :-)

Answer (score 2):

The output `event_pb2.py` content **sounds** correct.

Here's an example for a very basic `proto` file.

`event_pb2.py`:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: event.proto
"""Generated protocol buffer code."""
from google.protobuf.internal import builder as _builder
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pool as _descriptor_pool
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()




DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor_pool.Default().AddSerializedFile(b'\n\x0b\x65vent.proto\"\x15\n\x05\x45vent\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x01 \x01(\tb\x06proto3')

_globals = globals()
_builder.BuildMessageAndEnumDescriptors(DESCRIPTOR, _globals)
_builder.BuildTopDescriptorsAndMessages(DESCRIPTOR, 'event_pb2', _globals)
if _descriptor._USE_C_DESCRIPTORS == False:

  DESCRIPTOR._options = None
  _globals['_EVENT']._serialized_start=15
  _globals['_EVENT']._serialized_end=36
# @@protoc_insertion_point(module_scope)
```

The Python implementation of Protocol Buffers differs from e.g. Java, Golang and other languages.

`protoc`'s Python-generated code is only descriptors and the runtime produces the implementation. See [Python Generated Code Guide](https://protobuf.dev/reference/python/python-generated/).

The way to confirm this is to implement the `protoc`-generated stub code; it should work.

There's another 'trick' with `protoc` for Python to generate a descriptor that can be used by Visual Studio Code to provide intellisense. Add `--pyi_out` to `protoc` to get it to generate Python `.pyi` files. See [Python pyi file generation description](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10988).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this similar problem using the following line below (But I don't know if it works for this question):

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I '/home/mydir/Project/' --python_out='/home/mydir/Project/proto_out_folder' --grpc_python_out='/home/mydir/Project/proto_out_folder' '/home/mydir/Project/protofile.proto'
```

**Note:** Make sure you have installed grpcio and grpcio-tools ( I have pip3 installed following version: grpcio==1.32.0 and grpcio-tools==1.32.0). I am using Python 3.8.17 .

*It might not be needed, but I used following lines to pip3 install the grpc.*

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir  --force-reinstall -Iv grpcio==1.32.0
pip3 install --no-cache-dir  --force-reinstall -Iv grpcio-tools==1.32.0
```